# es6 harmony arrow functions in express handlers

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

Is there a reason not to use arrows instead of regular function expressions in expressjs for handlers in middleware?

```
app.use(mountSomething())
router.use(mountSomethingElse())

app.get('/', (req,res,next)=> { 
    next();
})

route.get('/path', (req,res,next)=>{
    res.send('send')
})
```

Comment: What makes you think that you shouldn't use arrow functions instead of regular functions?

Comment: @saadq I've edited the question

Comment: The only difference between a regular function expression and an arrow function is that the arrow function doesn't bind its own `this` value (You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)). So in a case like this where you won't need to use `this`, using an arrow function would be fine.

Comment: If you not using generators inside handlers, you can totally use fat arrows.

Comment: [No](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/1048572)

Answer (score 18):

```
app.get('/', (req,res,next)=> { 
    next();
})
```

is the same as

```
app.get('/', function(req,res,next) { 
        next();
}.bind(this))
```

In most cases you are not going to use 'this'(which will be probably undefined) in the handlers, so you are free to use arrow functions.